# TypeError: dayjs.utc is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, utc, dayjs

I am getting this error

> dayjs.utc is not a function

Here is my code

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')

console.log('utc time',dayjs.utc())
```

Comment: By default, Day.js comes with core code only and no installed plugin. https://dayjs.gitee.io/docs/en/plugin/plugin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Fix**: I tried this it's working:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc')
dayjs.extend(utc)

console.log('utc time',dayjs.utc())
```

Refer docs https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/utc

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the incorrect method in which you use `dayjs`.
See:

```js
var utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc')
dayjs.extend(utc)

// default local time
dayjs().format() //2019-03-06T17:11:55+08:00

// UTC mode
dayjs.utc().format() // 2019-03-06T09:11:55Z

// convert local time to UTC time
dayjs().utc().format() // 2019-03-06T09:11:55Z 

// While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.
// And all getters and setters will internally use the Date#getUTC* and Date#setUTC* methods instead of the Date#get* and Date#set* methods.
dayjs.utc().isUTC() // true
dayjs.utc().local().format() //2019-03-06T17:11:55+08:00
dayjs.utc('2018-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Mistake you did:

```js
var utc = require('dayjs')
```

Fix I shared:

```js
var utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc')
```

From : https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/utc

Comment: I'm getting this same error with Typescript modules and React. So, I'm using import statements. When I do the same thing I get this error: `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 0):

***If you using import:***

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'days/plugin/utc';
dayjs.extend(utc)
```